# How to take input for the struct type array in a bits field?

Tags: c++

I have just learned the bits field and then when I code for examples, i received this "error: cannot bind bitfield". Can you tell me the reason ?

```
#include<iostream>
using std :: cin;
using std :: cout;
short n, i, m;
struct ex {
    int p: 14;
    int m: 14;
} a[10005];
int main() {
    cin >> a[0].p;
    cout << a[0].p;
}
```

Comment: unless you are going to be doing coding on embedded systems with minimal system resources, you're not going to be using bitfields.  They are second class citizens in C++ and most of their behavior is implementation defined.

Comment: A bitfield is not addressable.  Therefore, the stream extraction operator cannot bind the reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

In short: bitfields are not addressable.

When you write

```
cin >> a[0].p;
```

the best fit would be to call

```
std::istream & operator >> (std::istream &, int &)
```

because members of the bitfield turn into the storage type used. There is no type for a 14bit subset of an int like you have in the bitfield and the type decays into a plain int.

But without the width and offset information the resulting pointer would cover the whole `int` and reading an int to `a[0].p` would overwrite `a[0].m`. So you can not take the address of a member of the bitfield and therefore the `operator >>` call can't work.